# setState Trigger build function twice

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm facing an issue with flutter, somehow my child widget is built twice when I setState on the parent. This caused an error with the hero because there are multiple widgets with the same tag.

As you can see I added the prints to test it and as I thought "parent building" printed once and "child building" printed twice.

Also, it happens only on Cupertino platform

my parent code:

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  HomeState createState() {
    return new HomeState();
  }
}
final _pageOptions = [
  ProfileTab(),
  TrainingTab(),

];
class HomeState extends State<MainPage> {
  int _selectedTabIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('parent building');
    return PlatformScaffold(
      body: _pageOptions[_selectedTabIndex],
      bottomNavBar: PlatformNavBar(
        currentIndex: _selectedTabIndex,
        itemChanged: (index) => setState((){
            _selectedTabIndex = index;
          }),
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: tr('MY_ACC'),
            icon: PlatformWidget(
              cupertino: (_, __) => Icon(CupertinoIcons.person),
              material: (_, __) => Icon(Icons.person),
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: tr('MY_TRG'),
            icon: PlatformWidget(
              cupertino: (_, __) => Icon(CupertinoIcons.news),
              material: (_, __) => Icon(Icons.view_list),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      iosContentPadding: true,
      iosContentBottomPadding: true,
    );
  }
}
```

my child code:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_platform_widgets/flutter_platform_widgets.dart';
import 'package:group_app/pages/edit_profile_page.dart';
import 'package:group_app/widgets/PlatformWidgets/PlatformListTile.dart';
import 'package:skeleton_text/skeleton_text.dart';
Widget _flightShuttleBuilder(
    BuildContext flightContext,
    Animation<double> animation,
    HeroFlightDirection flightDirection,
    BuildContext fromHeroContext,
    BuildContext toHeroContext,
    ) {
  return DefaultTextStyle (
    style:  new TextStyle(fontSize: Theme.of(toHeroContext).textTheme.headline5.fontSize),
    child: toHeroContext.widget,
  );
}
final rng = new Random();
class ProfileTab extends StatefulWidget {
  ProfileTab({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _StatefulStatePlatform();
  }
}
class _StatefulStatePlatform extends State<ProfileTab> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('child building');
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    return SafeArea(
       child: Column(
           children: [
             PlatformListTile(
               leading: auth.currentUser == null ? null : Hero(
                   tag: 'profilePhoto',
                   child: ClipOval(
                       child: CachedNetworkImage(
                         width: 75.0,
                         imageUrl: auth.currentUser.photoURL,)
                   )
               ),
               title:  auth.currentUser == null ? null : Hero(
                   flightShuttleBuilder: _flightShuttleBuilder,
                   tag: 'displayName',
                   child: Text(auth.currentUser.displayName, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6)
               ),
               subtitle:tr('TAP_EDIT_PROFILE'),
               isLeadingSkeleton: auth.currentUser == null,
               onPressed: () => {Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/edit-profile')},

             ),
             Divider(),
             PlatformListTile(
               leading: Icon(context.platformIcons.group),
               title: tr("MY_REGI"),
               subtitle: tr("MY_REGI_EXPLAIN"),
               onPressed: () => {print("clicked")},
             ),
             PlatformListTile(
               leading: Icon(context.platformIcons.info),
               title: tr("MY_REGI"),
               subtitle: tr("MY_REGI_EXPLAIN"),
               onPressed: () => {showAboutDialog(context: context)},
             )
           ]
       )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter and build occurences :)

I think your `Profile` is built once on  `_pageOptions` declaration :

```
final _pageOptions = [
  ProfileTab(), // first build
  TrainingTab(),
];
```

and twice when you get the reference of `_pageOptions` which will call `ProfileTab()` again :

```
body: _pageOptions[_selectedTabIndex], // second build
```

You can instanciate your Tabs in the 'initState()' method like this.

```
ProfileTab profileTab;
TrainingTab trainingTab;
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  profileTab = ProfileTab();
  trainingTab = TrainingTab();
  _pageOptions = [profileTab, trainingTab];
}.
```

If it not fix your issue, you could always debug your code and check the stacktrace to understand where they are built.

Comment: so what you suggest me to do?
Also, I forgot to mention its happen only with Cupertino platform

Comment: hi, still not works can you explain to me what is stacktrace?

Comment: when you debug your app and put a breakpoint on your build method, you should check your debug view and look at methods called before

Comment: hi do you have discord or skype so you can help me?

Comment: sorry I can't help you more today, try to search how to debug your app